# else if condition concept

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I need to check in two of string, if those string contains any particular string or not

```
 NSString *startLocationAddress = @"Any address for start location";
 NSString *endLocationAddress = @"Any address for end location";

 if ([startLocationAddress rangeOfString:@"Australia"].location == NSNotFound)
 {
     NSLog(@"string does not contain Australia");
     startLocationAddress = [startLocationAddress stringByAppendingString:@",Australia"];
 }
 else if ([endLocationAddress rangeOfString:@"Australia"].location == NSNotFound)
 {
     NSLog(@"string does not contain Australia");
     endLocationAddress =[endLocationAddress stringByAppendingString:@",Australia"];
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"string contain Australia");
 }
```

As my both of strings does not contains "Australia". So the first condition will be checked first and if the first condition valid then it exit out of the conditions, if the first condition is not valid then only it check the else if condition. In this way the if else if conditional works.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  And what is the actual behavior?

Comment: In if else clause if any one case is satisfied then the other cases will not be checked

Comment: You just want 2 if statements, not an else if...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better reconstruct it like:

```
 if ([startLocationAddress rangeOfString:@"Australia"].location == NSNotFound)
 {
     //codes..
 }
 else
 {
    NSLog(@"startLocationAddress contain Australia");
 }

 if ([endLocationAddress rangeOfString:@"Australia"].location == NSNotFound)
 {
     //codes..
 }
 else 
 {
     NSLog(@"endLocationAddress contain Australia");
 }
```

and review how ***if***-***else if***-***else*** statement works.. See: @
Hanky 웃 Panky answer for that, since confusion is very prone to us..

```
if (ifcondition)
{ .. }
else if (elseifcondition)
{ .. }
else
{ .. }
/*
 if `ifcondition` == true, dont expect anything from `else-if` or `else`, 
 compiler won't care about them anymore. that goes with `else-if` and `else` as well.. 
*/
```

Comment: `You better` change the wording on this answer. hehe joking. If you didn't know `You better` doesn't really mean `It will be better to`. It is kinda forceful :)

Answer (score 4):

> As my both of strings does not contains "Australia". First if condition is working fine and it append "Australia" to the string but second else if condition is not working

How on earth can an `else if` block execute when it's corresponding `if` was executed? Expectation is not logical.

If you want your `else if` block to also check then separate it from your main `if` and start a new `if` condition, not an `else if`

Comment: Panky, agreed my fault, the code i posted is not logical, confused with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

In if-else if-else condition if any of one is gets satisfied it will ignore the rest of the condition.
This means if First if gets satisfied, then it will ignore the "else if - else". Hence your second condition is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to read the basic `if else` logic of execution.

Here is the example

```
int x=70;
string Grade;

IF (x > 90) THEN
Grade = "O"
ELSE IF (x > 80) THEN
Grade = "A"
ELSE IF (x > 70) THEN
Grade = "B"
ELSE IF (x > 60) THEN
Grade = "C"
ELSE
Grade = "F"
```

Here the value for variable `Grade` will be only one per execution.